# Problem with the house mannequin disappearing

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok, so I have two mannequin inside my brand new house in Solitude.  Anytime I put anything on them for armor that particular body part disapears until there isn't even a stand showing but it is still there if I mouse-over it.  If I remove anything on it, it all reappears except for the piece I removed (of course).

Is this a known bug or are there any workarounds?  I'd like to put something on them to just keep it handy but I dont want to risk it eating whatever I put on them.

Thanks.

edit: on the PS3 so console commands not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug.  Your stuff isn't gone; it's just that the mannequin can't render the armor. Very strange, actually.

If it helps, there are lots of bugs around housing.  In Windhelm (at Hjerm), I can make a staff stick out into the hallway by putting it in a display case. Kind of cool, in a Poltergeist sort of way.

Comment: guess I just wont bother using them until a fix bubbles its way down.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that works for me: place all the armor on a mannequin that you want to appear then add any necklace. Exit from the mannequin menu and reenter the menu and remove the necklace, after this the outfit should appear on the mannequin.