# Vlindrel Hall house mannequin never appears

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

[Some folks have had trouble with their mannequins disappearing once you hang armor on them.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44378/problem-with-the-house-mannequin-disappearing)

My problem's worse - for me, the mannequin never appeared in the first place! I bought Vlindrel Hall, the player house in Markarth. [There is supposed to be a mannequin in the living room](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vlindrel_Hall) once you buy the living room furnishings, as I did before I went inside the house for the first time.

Unfortunately, my living room has the pedestal in the corner where the mannequin should be, but no visible mannequin. Trying to interact with the mannequin by pressing E doesn't work either, so it seems the mannequin truly doesn't exist, or has glitched itself into a place the player cannot reach or see. How might I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out! Had the same issue. For me it resolved itself when I purchased the enchanting lab. For some reason the mannequin comes with enchantment furnishings. I hope this comes not too late! Felt bad you got no good answer